# C# regarding using filenames to map documents dynamically to a folder structure how to

Tags: directory

Currently I am trying to use C# (C sharp) to do a traverse meaning. 
I have a filename which is broken into 3 elements e.g monster3456 test. Monster is a name, the numbers are a unique set and test is a code that really stands for Testers. Anyway there is a folder structure that I have setup which starts at

the Alpha level so every alphabet A, B, C, D, ....M
then breaks down to names where Monster 3456 would be a name in the M breakdown
and then in the Monster folder I have 3 subfolders called Tester, Maker and Builder.

I would like to dynamically have the filename monster3456 test, map to the folder That has the M - alpha and then the name monster 3456 and then to the subfolder Tester. There will be different instances with different files having different codes needing to go to one of the 3 subfolders. I am new to programming and looking for some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood correctly - hopefully this will get you started.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string basePath = "c:\\temp";

            List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
            filenames.Add("monster3456 test");
            filenames.Add("ketchup1234 make");
            filenames.Add("oranges5555 build");

            foreach (string filename in filenames)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(filename, @"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)[^\S]{1,}(\w+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    string alpha = match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(0, 1);
                    string alphaString = match.Groups[1].Value;
                    string uniqueSet = match.Groups[2].Value;
                    string instance = match.Groups[3].Value;
                    string finalInstance = String.Empty;
                    string path = String.Empty;

                    switch (instance.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "test":
                            finalInstance = "Tester";
                            break;
                        case "make":
                            finalInstance = "Maker";
                            break;
                        case "build":
                            finalInstance = "Builder";
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(finalInstance))
                    {
                        path = basePath + "\\" + alpha + "\\" + alphaString + uniqueSet + "\\" + finalInstance;
                        Console.WriteLine(path);
                        /* Console.WriteLine("alpha: " + alpha);
                        Console.WriteLine("alphaString: " + alphaString);
                        Console.WriteLine("uniqueSet: " + uniqueSet);
                        Console.WriteLine("finalInstance: " + finalInstance); */
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
c:\temp\m\monster3456\Tester
c:\temp\k\ketchup1234\Maker
c:\temp\o\oranges5555\Builder
```